# How to get packages of a class name in Java

Tags: java

I found this 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getpackage.htm

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.lang.*;

public class ClassDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

     try {
        Class cls = Class.forName("java.lang.Integer");

        // returns the name and package of the class
        System.out.println("Class = " + cls.getName());
        System.out.println("Package = " + cls.getPackage());
     }
     catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
     }
   }
}
```

This getpackage method requires I know already the package name and the class name to get the package name.

What I wish is a getpackages method which returns all the package of a given class name.

Comment: You probably need to iterate through whatever's returned by the `getPackages()` method of your `ClassLoader`.

Comment: One class can have only one package declaration then what means all the package of a given class name?

Comment: Your statement is untrue. The `Class.forName()` method requires that you know the package, but there are many other ways of getting a `Class`, most obviously from an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **getPackage().getName()** of the class [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getPackage())

## Example

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test t = new Test();
        String packageName = t.getClass().getPackage().getName();
        System.out.println("Package Name = " + packageName);

        //and without any instance:
        String packageName2 = Test.class.getPackage().getName();
        System.out.println("Package Name no instance  = " + packageName2);      }
}
```

Comment: You have to instantiate : can't we do without ?

Comment: @user310291 Sure, just use `Test.class.getPackage().getName()`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel How exactly does that help? The class's package name has to be mentioned either inline in the code you mentioned or in an `import` statement.

Comment: @EJP It answers the question if you can do it without instantiating: you can. If it useful: probably not.

Comment: OP wants to return all the packages that have a class with a particular name.  This returns only one package - it doesn't answer the question.